# Amazon S3 wildcards in copy folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, partial

Is it possible to copy folders using wildcards? For example I have a folder that under that has folders names in some date format for example 2022-02-22 and I want to copy only some of the folders, for example 2022-02-*.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Exclude and Include Filters** ([explained here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)) to achive what you want.
In your case , you can do `aws s3 cp s3://Myfolder/ /MyLocalFolder --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2022-02*"`